# Radial text with html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to write some text radiating out from a specified radius.

In other words I'm trying to write text in a circular pattern, but radiating out from som defined inner radius.

Edit: I'm trying to write text between the lines in this example: http://mandelid.com/code/wheel/

Comment: Sounds tricky. Do you have a question?

Comment: The question is: Can anyone help me? :) The example at http://mandelid.com/code/wheel is an actual canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wisely the context transform and you're done.

Steps :
• translate to the circle center.
• rotate the context by your angle
• translate horizontally to get to the start of the text
• draw text.

```js
var cv = document.getElementById('cv');
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');

function drawText(txt, x, y, angle, radius) {
  ctx.textAlign = 'left';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(x, y)
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.translate(radius, 0);
  ctx.fillText(txt, 0, 0);
  ctx.restore();
}

drawText('Hello Folks', 100, 100, -Math.PI / 4, 20);

drawText('How are you ?', 100, 100, Math.PI / 4, 20);
```

```html
<canvas width=300 height=200 id='cv'></canvas>
```

Comment: +1 For a concise answer that fits the questioners need.  You might make a visual improvement by having text at angles PI/2 through PI*3/2 be right-side-up instead of upside-down.